# simple json load giving invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying a simple `json.load`

```
import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.stubhub.com/ticketAPI/restSvc/event/4100000/sort/price/0/')
data = json.load(response)
```

and am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 590, in _readall_chunked
    chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 562, in _read_next_chunk_size
    return int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\n'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.load(url)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 271, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 509, in read
    return self._readall_chunked()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 594, in _readall_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(16384 bytes read)
```

Based on the error I can't really figure out what might be going on here. Could anyone shed some light on how to get around this?

**Edit:**
Using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module works, but I'd rather use the core Python modules if possible.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.stubhub.com/ticketAPI/restSvc/event/4100000/sort/price/0/')
data = json.loads(r.text)
```

Comment: try `data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @razpeitia same error, when doing that. It seems the error is when reading the data from the url and not in the json parsing, atleast that is what I've gathered from the traceback.

Comment: @razpeitia, use json.load**s** and post it as an answer, you are right.

Comment: This might be related to http://bugs.python.org/issue14044

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.stubhub.com/ticketAPI/restSvc/event/4100000/sort/price/0/')
data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I'm still get the same error. Python33... If I use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module like someone else mentioned it works fine for me. But I don't really wanna have to use an external module, I'd rather use the core modules.